# The getElementById () method returns null, the script indicated at the end of the document

Tags: javascript, html

Method getElementById() returns null

I took into account that javascript is executed before loading HTML elements, so I pointed the script at the end of the body tag, but to no avail

```html
<button id="button">Начать программу</button>
<div class="firstArray">Ваши числа: </div>
<div class="newArray">Вывод: </div>
<script>
document.getElementById('firstArray').innerHTML = 'Ваши числа: ' + arr +
  '<br>'; // document.getElementById('firstArray') is null
</script>
```

Comment: you are looking for an `id` but you setted a `class` in the element...
`getElementBy*Id*`

Comment: change  the  class to id in `<div class="firstArray">Ваши числа: </div>`

Comment: @raman Better to work with classes than IDs.

Comment: Additionally you haven't ever  defined `arr`

Comment: Thank!  I understood my mistake.  I wrote only part of the code, arr was defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById()` does just that. You don't have an element with that `id`. You have an element with a `class`. Use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead:

```html
<button id="button">Начать программу</button>
<div class="firstArray">Ваши числа: </div>
<div class="newArray">Вывод: </div>
<script>
  var arr = "test";
  document.querySelector('.firstArray').innerHTML = 'Ваши числа: ' + arr + '<br>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your `<div>` to have an `id=""` rather than a `class=""`. Specify the name of the `id` with `<div id="your_id_goes_here"> ... </div>` and target it using the `getElementById()` method, specifying the `id` name as the function parameter.

Comment: You don't "need" to change the class to an id. In fact, it's better to work with classes  than IDs as ID based solutions become brittle and don't scale. Use `.querySelector()` when working with classes.

Comment: You'll need to change it to an `id` to use `getElementById()` is all I had meant. Good point though!

Comment: But, you'll need to change it to `.querySelector()` if you have a class. Since the HTML is already built, it makes more sense to modify the JavaScript to do the right query than to go back and make the HTML more brittle and less scalable just so the query will work.